# Making or Demonstrating Principle of Electron Microscope

Tags: electrons, microscopy

is it possible to either demonstrate the principle or make a SEM  ( electron microscope ) at home or lab as an enthusiast??
and how can i start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Yes, you can!" © :-)

Check out this guy on YouTube, he has described everything in detail:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdjYVF4a6iU (and his related videos)

Basically he used an electron gun from a small TV-tube, using phosphor and photomultiplier to detect electrons. Image is shown on an analog oscilloscope.

Although it is doable at home, this is not exactly a weekend project.

Comment: :D i know ..... i am interested in it ...thats why i am going for it!

Comment: what will be the estimated cost for this?

Comment: @SiddharthaSinha They only expensive part is good vacuum pump. 2-stage chineese pump is about 200 dollars . If it would not be enough - adding used turbomolecular pump might cost ~1000 dollars and more. Everything else might be salvaged from old TV's for free.

Comment: seriously for free???????

Comment: You will need considerable facility with electronics to salvage the needed parts for free, but if you had come to my house last week I could have given you two good quality CRTs for free. I was expected to have to pay US$5 each to dispose of them before a cross-country move.

Comment: it would be of tremendous help if you can give me a link for SEM ... and related formulae

Comment: where can i get a photomultiplier and phosphor?? @dmckee and @ barsmonster

Comment: The display end of a typical TV tube is a phosphor screen. Getting PMTs is harder, but they can sometimes be scrounged from people cleaning out old labs. In US academic circles the funding agencies like to see parts that they bought passed on to another one of their clients so that kind of thing happens a lot. I don't know how that or something similar might apply to your situation.

Comment: and where do i get a oscilloscope??

Comment: @SiddharthaSinha You could post on your local messageboard a message that you are buying old analog osciloscope. They are usually quite cheap as everyone are migrating to digital oscilloscopes.

Comment: is an analog oscilloscope same as CRT?

Comment: @SiddharthaSinha Well, yes you need CRT-based oscilloscope. But it should be fully working, unlike TV's for parts.

Comment: from where do i "salvage" oscilloscopes? @dmckee andbarsmonster ( thnk u for sparing so much time)

Comment: can this be used for vacuum pump ..actaully the matter is that i want to make it from scratch... and get reasonable magnififcation,,..[link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lrAcJ67b78

Comment: or a modification of it...using a fridge compressor?

Comment: @SiddharthaSinha Oscilloscopes are not usually free, unfortunately. Fridge compressor is too weak for this, you need better vacuum.

Comment: Is there any way ... i can demonstrate the basic princple of SEM ...???

Comment: http://www.stcloudstate.edu/cmia/documents/SEMQAe.pdf i found this .... so can i detect X rays for the image???